# How to force disconnect from Windows Remote Apps command line

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-gateway

I have a RDP connection that is initiated by a RD Gateway website.
Login and everything works well.

But sometimes the connection becomes a ghost, or if i want to login as another user on the same RD Gateway via RDP i have to manually press the

```
Disconnect from all connection/apps
```

[image: Disconnect from all connection/apps]

Does anyone know how i get the that disconnect function by command line?
The connection does not appear in Query Uers for example

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so it seems like

```
taskkill /F /IM "wksprt.exe"
```

Kills the RemoteApps connection that is causing my connections issues when using multiple usernames on same RD Gateway :)

Reference: https://www.sevecek.com/EnglishPages/_layouts/mobile/disppost.aspx?List=f6e49214%2Da43d%2D4fa5%2D9537%2Dfb46eabe0cb8&ID=85